# Rails: Method to check the database appointment is not taken - not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very beginners understanding of rails and ruby and I keep
getting stuck. If anyone could please point out my where I'm going wrong, that would be great! Or else, is there an easier way to validate the database before I allow an appointment? I don't want double bookings.

I am making an appointment booking app and I have a very basic design. I
have created an appointments scaffold with name:string phone:string
email:string numpeople:integer date:date timeslot:string. 
In the view for creating a new appointment I have stated that appointment 1 is
9-11am, appointment 2 is 12-2pm, appointment 3 is 3-5pm and appointment
4 is 5 - 7pm. The user is asked to enter 1,2,3 or 4.

When the user clicks on "make appointment" I'm trying to interrupt the
appointments controller (create method)  so that I can check if the date
&& timeslot are nil. if that is the case, the system should continue on
to create the appointment, if not then I want to redirect to somewhere
else. I have created a method called isValid? in the model (See below)

I think the method is correct as the system is getting as far as the
redirect. Tclass Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base

   def isValid?
      taken = Appointment.where("date = ? && timeslot = ?", date, timeslot)
      save unless taken
end
end
```

The problem is, it keeps redirecting to the page I told it to
go to if it's not saved(the homepage or root_path). (Also the
appointments are not saving).

appointments controller create method:

```
def create
  valid = @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params).isValid?

  respond_to do |format|
  if valid
    format.html { redirect_to new_appointment_path, notice: 'Appointment was 
    successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @appointment }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to appointments_path, notice: 'That appointment 
    is not available, please choose again' } # this redirect works with no 
    notice
    format.js { render json: @appointment.errors, status: 
    :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Full appointments controller class: (In case I've missed something)

```
 class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_appointment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
   @appointments = Appointment.all
end

def show
end

def new
   @appointment = Appointment.new
end

def edit
end

def create
  valid = @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params).isValid?

  respond_to do |format|
  if valid
    format.html { redirect_to new_appointment_path, notice: 'Appointment was 
    successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @appointment }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to appointments_path, notice: 'That appointment 
    is not available, please choose again' } # this redirect works with no 
    notice
    format.js { render json: @appointment.errors, status: 
    :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
   respond_to do |format|
   if @appointment.update(appointment_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was 
      successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @appointment }
   else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: 
      :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
  end

def destroy
   @appointment.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to appointments_url, notice: 'Appointment was 
     successfully destroyed.' }
     format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_appointment
     @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list 
through.

def appointment_params
  params.require(:appointment).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :numpeople, 
  :date, :timeslot)
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your method should be something like:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base

   def isValid?
      taken = Appointment.where("date = ? && timeslot = ?", date, timeslot)
      save unless taken.present?
   end
end
```

Let me know if that works.